# Group-by if all field results are true

Tags: sql, group-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    tbl_ord.ord.table,
    tbl_ord.ord.n_ord,
    player.confirm
FROM 
    tbl_ord
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_players ON tbl_ord.player_id = tbl_players.player_ids
WHERE 
    id_shop = 3
ORDER BY 
    n_ord ASC
```

result:

```
+-----------+-------+---------+
| ord_table | n_ord | confirm |
+-----------+-------+---------+
|        10 |     2 |       1 |
|        10 |     2 |       0 |
|         8 |     3 |       1 |
|         8 |     3 |       1 |
|         4 |     5 |       1 |
|         4 |     5 |       1 |
+-----------+-------+---------+
```

I'd like get only result with all confirmed users by group-by on ord_table

```
+-----------+-------+---------+
| ord_table | n_ord | confirm |
+-----------+-------+---------+
|         4 |     5 |       1 |
|         8 |     3 |       1 |
+-----------+-------+---------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use  `not exists`:

```
SELECT o.ord_table, o.ord.n_ord,
       1 as confirm
FROM tbl_ord o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_players p 
                  WHERE o.player_id = p.player_ids AND
                        ?.id_shop = 3 AND  -- not sure what table this comes from
                        p.confirm = 0
                 )   
ORDER BY o.n_ord ASC;
```

The advantage of this approach is that it avoids aggregating at the outer level.  This, in turn, means that it can make better use of indexes, including using an index to potentially avoid sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
  tbl_ord.ord.table,
  tbl_ord.ord.n_ord,
  MIN(player.confirm)
FROM tbl_ord
INNER JOIN tbl_players ON tbl_ord.player_id = tbl_players.player_ids
WHERE id_shop = 3
GROUP BY tbl_ord.ord.table, tbl_ord.ord.n_ord,
HAVING MIN(player.confirm) = 1
ORDER BY n_ord ASC
```